# Threads & networking issue

Tags: java

Given the following code:

```
 Client c1 = new Client();
 c1.connect("127.0.0.1",1300);
```

Connect function:

```
public void connect(String serverName, int port)
{
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverName,port);
        connection = new ConnectionProxy(socket);
        connection.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(`ConnectionProxy` class extends `Thread`) :

```
public class ConnectionProxy extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
private InputStream is;
private OutputStream os;
private StringConsumer client;

public ConnectionProxy(Socket socket)
{
    this.socket = socket;

    try {
        is = socket.getInputStream();
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void run () {

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

    while (socket != null)
    {
        try {
            String msg = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a chat and I'm finding it difficult to send a message written by a client to all of the currently connected clients.

How could I do that? Should I hold the reference for each object (like c1) on the server side, or should I hold that `ConnectionProxy` thread on the server side?
If not, how do I implement that correctly and efficiently?

Would love to get some help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being given much code, I'll outline what you'd want to do to achieve your goal.

On your `server`:

- Keep an `array` or something similar of all connected `client` objects
- Implement a `send()` function in your `client` class
- Implement a `broadcast()` function that loops through the client list and sends each of them the message (using the aforementioned `send()` function
- Make sure to keep track of (and remove) any dead/disconnected `clients` from your list, otherwise you'll run into trouble trying to send to them.

On your `client`:

- Make sure you send a "connection terminated" message when you close/disconnect to tell the `server` you're leaving (makes it easier for the server to remove you)

Answer (score 0):

The server should create a new client handler thread for each incoming connection.

For example, on the server side try something like:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

    while (true) {
        Socket client = server.accept();
        //add incoming client to connected clients vector.
        HandleClient c = new HandleClient(client);
        clients.add(c);
    }
```

After creating and storing clients in your vector of clients, you can the implement on the HandleClient class run() method a bufferReader (again not a must) to get your client text